# how to apply the rewrite rule in htaccess in php for this url

Tags: php, url-rewriting

url:
  http://www.kashmirmart.com/display.php?cat_id=52&subcat_id=53&name=Woolen_Shawls

here cat id , subcate id and name are always dynamic values

i want to rewrite like this:

```
http://www.kashmirmart.com/parentname/subcatname/page
```

for example:

```
http://www.kashmirmart.com/handicraft-industry/kashmir-craft/Woolen_Shawls
```

handicraft-industry is parent 
 kashmir-craft is subcategory under the handicraft-industry
 Woolen_Shawls is the last detailed page listed in kashmir-craft

plz give me solution as early as possible
 thanks

Comment: URLs can't contain spaces. Also please show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example...You can modify based on your requirements.

> http://www.pets.com/show_a_product.php?product_id={a number}

And you want to change them to look like this:

> http://www.pets.com/products/{a number}/

In order to do so, you will need to use "regular expressions". These are patterns, defined in a specific format that the server can understand and handle appropriately. A typical pattern to identify a number would look like this:

> [0-9]+

The square brackets contain a range of characters, and "0-9" indicates all the digits. The plus symbol indicates that the pattern will idenfiy one or more of whatever precedes the plus - so this pattern effectively means "one or more digits" - exactly what we're looking to find in our URL.

The entire "pattern" part of the rule is treated as a regular expression by default - you don't need to turn this on or activate it at all.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    show_a_product.php?product_id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Comment: but here i am not passing a single value bro.There are three values so how can made the regular expression for that url and can`t change the url`s passing value because i need it for some function calling inside the page....... thanks for your feedback bro

Comment: Just go through this website bro...http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/
Dnt forget to upvote.